# The primary key read from the row is null

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am using jpa and trying to do a native named query here is my query

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="getDataByList", query="SELECT DISTINCT   
p.SHIPMENT_NUMBER, p.PO_NUMBERS FROM Packing_Data p WHERE p.PACKING_ID = ?1", 
resultClass = PackingData.class)
```

I am getting this error `The primary key read from the row [ArrayRecord(` becuase I am not selecting the primary key from the `Packing_Data` table, but I a select that column then the `DISTINCT` part not longer works?

How get I select distinct rows?

Thanks

Comment: post the exception+stack trace, PackingData class.

Comment: Your query doesn't return PackingData instances. It returns shipment numbers. You shouldn't try to get PackingData instances from such a query. And BTW, it doesn't need to be native. Just use `select distinct p.shipmentNumber from PackingData p where p.packing.id = ?1` This JPQL query will return a List<String> (assuming the type of shipmentNumber is String).

Comment: @JBNizet what if I was selecting SHIPMENT NUMBERS AND PO NUMBERS and wanted it to be mapped, can that be done?

Comment: Yes. You would then receive a List<Object[]>, where each array has two elements: the shipment number and the po number.

Comment: @JBNizet right, but is there a way where it would return the PackingData Object, or a way to map it to PackingData Object after the query

Comment: If you use an entity to map it will always expect a primary key. As JB Nizet mentioned retrieve the List<Object[]> and then transform it into the class of your need

Comment: @Acewin okay got that wokring is there an easier way to map it after the query, than just looping though as doing using the setters

Comment: Not exactly. mostly because hibernate expects primary key to be unique and not null, without allowing a primary key it wont let you map a class to your output. I recently tried to retrieve data from a table and forgot to ad @Id entity hibernate failed loading of application stating that it expects an Id to be there in the class

Comment: You should really not do that. A caller calling your method, returning an entity, will expect the entity to respect its invariants: have its ID and all its fields set, be managed, be able to navigate through its associations, etc. If you query returns two fields, create a type containing these two fields, and return that. Your code will be self-descriptive and reliable.